# This curl command doesn't work for some reason

Tags: php, curl

I have a URL that I need to "call" from a PHP script. The URL makes a phone call using Tropo's API, so it's easy to verify if it was called.

My PHP looks like this:

```
<?php

$oid=$_GET["oid"];
$notify_url = "http://mydomain.com/somepath/".$oid;
echo $notify_url;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $notify_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

mail('me@gmail.com', 'cURL', "Did a cURL");

?>
```

This prints out the $notify_url variable, and when I take the printed value and enter it into a browser window, I get the desired result i.e. the phone call to my phone.

I have tried this on two web hosts that claim they support CURL, one is paid (crazydomains.com.ayu - just got off the phone to support) and the other is 000webhost.com

Am I doing something wrong? This one is kind of confusing, since it should be so simple.

EDIT: I receive the mail as expected.

EDIT 2: If you have any ideas about how I can debug this, I would appreciate it.

EDIT 3: As Juhana suggested I added `echo curl_error();` after curl_exec and I got this error ...

`Warning: Wrong parameter count for curl_error() in /home/a5352876/public_html/curl.php on line 15`

EDIT 4: changed the `echo curl_error()` to `echo curl_error($ch)` and got the message `couldn't connect to host` so that seems to be the problem.

Now the question is, why can't it connect to a host that is easily accessible through a browser, is there anywhere I can look for that?

Comment: You see the printed `notify_url`, you get the phone call, and email comes in as expected. What is the issue?

Comment: Does `echo curl_error()` give anything?

Comment: @Josh I get the phone call if I manually enter the URL into a browser, the script doesn't give me a phone call. I.e. I have the correct URL but it is not being called by my script.

Comment: @Juhana I'll give it ago and let you know.

Comment: @Juhana I tried it and got Warning: Wrong parameter count for curl_error() in /home/a5352876/public_html/curl.php on line 16 .... will update the question.

Comment: @Ankur Ah, thanks for the clarification. I overlooked that you wrote, *enter it into a browser window*.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `echo curl_error($ch)`

Comment: if you add it after curl_close you'll ask for errors on a deleted curl handle, add it after curl_exec

Comment: @Harald yes I made that mistake initially, then did as you say.

Comment: you're forgetting the handle `echo curl_error($ch);`

Comment: @Harald I've added that and I get the error "couldn't connect to host"

Comment: do `echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen');` and `echo ini_get('allow_url_include');`to see if your server doesn't limit you there

Comment: @Harald ... the answer to that is 10 ... I'm not sure what this means, I'll dig around.

Comment: Actually thats 1 and 0 for the two different echo commands. According to  http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php these are the defaults. But what they mean I still have to find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your host has HTTP wrappers enabled, and the `allow_url_fopen` config option is enabled, then you don't need cURL, especially for such a simple request.

It looks like all you need to do is open a URL, which you can easily do with [`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen):

```
$oid = $_GET["oid"];
$notify_url = "http://mydomain.com/somepath/".$oid;
$fh = fopen( $notify_url, 'r');
fclose( $fh);
```

Comment: Thanks Nick giving it a shot now.

Comment: @Ankur - Based on your curl error, it may not work, as your host may be blocking these sorts of connections. Just because you can load it in your browser, does not mean your server is able to access it.

Comment: Yeah I suspect so, the thing is both of these hosting companies say they have curl support and doing a phpInfo() supports this. But this didn't work either, actually I had to add another parameter to the fopen(). I read this and added an 'r' for read only. But it seems the host is blocking these kinds of things as you say.

Comment: Thanks for your help Nick, I believe your answer is actually correct, and may solve the problem for someone else. So even though it won't solve my situation, it does solve the problem of not getting cURL to work and so I'll accept it.